# C2440 when I try to initialize a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion

When I try to simply initialize a `std::vector` of `float[4]` I get a C2440 compiler error. I have got this error message:

> error C2440: `return` : cannot convert from `float [4]` to `float (&&)[4]`

`C2440Exemple.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class C2440Exemple
{
public:
    C2440Exemple();
    ~C2440Exemple();

private:
    std::vector<float[4]> normData;
};
```

`C2440Exemple.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C2440Exemple.h"

C2440Exemple::C2440Exemple()
{
    normData = std::vector<float[4]>(); // error C2440
}

C2440Exemple::~C2440Exemple()
{
}
```

I was on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx), but don't get a total understanding about why I get C2440. Any ideas?

Comment: And also I don't know exactly what means float(&&) ??? It means float & ?

Comment: Ignoring for a moment your problem, your _solution_ is to use `std::vector<std::array<float, 4>>`.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem on neither g++ nor clang. Maybe a compiler issue. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: @old_mountain : Illegal code doesn't always get the same diagnostics. And clang doesn't seem to like this much, nor should it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4c2b3c536a09473

Comment: Works in VS2015 Upd 1

Comment: Can anybody explain to me what means float(&&)[4] ? This requires a reference maybe ?

Comment: @ildjarn with default arguments I had no problems. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea8b4f02aad62adc

Comment: @old_mountain : As before, that is libstdc++ being lenient; a more conformant implementation complains: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaa1d90c60526446